# What the accepted way to persist variables in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, windows-services

I have a windows service which will be running all the time, but will only activate if it has been at least 24 hours since the last time.  Therefore I need to store the time and date since  it last carried out it's payload.

To do this I was thinking of writing to the App.Config with:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("LastRunTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

however this doesn't seem to persist, but rather cache which is no good if the service is restarted.

So what is the accepted method for persisting values for a windows service?

Comment: I think it rather depends, often storing data in a database is a good idea. Perhaps a simple text file might be less cumbersome.

Comment: Can you specify a different location for your app settings, the user folder?  My guess would be that it isn't persisting because of security in system32?

Comment: Can't you use System.Configuration.Configuration.Save() or .SaveAs()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up serializing the object as per [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) and inline with what @ChrisBint said I saved it into a text file.  This is what I was looking for as 'accepted', I knew I could write to text files but it was the method I was looking for.  I wanted to keep everything structured and strongly typed instead of writing my own methods for persisting data.

Since @Chris only provided a part answer I've upvoted him and accepted this.

Comment: 'Accepted'? By whom? While I appreciate the upvote, your question asked what is the accepted method for persisting values for a windows service and that link is certainly not that, it is standard serialization techniques. Your question also does not ask for implementation details, just suggestions on how this can be done. Based on this, I have downvoted this as I do not feel it represents anything like an answer (of which to be honest I feel there will not be for this question)

Comment: @ChrisBint - I understand what you're saying, it's probably a failure on my behalf to ask a proper question and I'll think about deleting it since there likely isn't anything of future value here.

Answer (score 7):

Use a database, simple xml/text file, registry value.

Also, based on your requirements, a simple console app run using Task scheduler may be another option.

Comment: That's fair enough, but database is overkill for a simple value.  So what's the accepted way?  I already mentioned the console app to management, they wern't interested in that method.

Comment: Do what you feel is best. If DB is overkill, use a text/xml file or a registry value. You are probably not going to find an 'accepted' method for this, just personal preferences.

Comment: Do you need concurrency? Bear in mind when using a text file.